# How to perform multiple commands for each file I find

Tags: linux, unix, find

So I am searching for files in a specific directory and for each file I find I want to perform a bunch of the same commands on these files.

I search for these files with this find command:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**While loop is your friend then**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file*" | while read file; do
   echo $file;
   # perform other operations on $file here
done
```

**If you are not a friend of the while loop**

```
$ ls -1 file*
file.txt
file1.txt

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file*" | xargs -n1 -I_val -- sh -c 'echo command1_val; echo command2_val'
command1./file.txt
command2./file.txt
command1./file1.txt
command2./file1.txt
```

In the command above _val is used instead of {} to avoid unnecessary quoting ([inspired by](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56738/350799))

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without a while loop? Maybe with grouping?

Comment: @ronaldmcd I have updated my answer with an example using xargs.